# Drag and Drop list not working after removing and appending list via Ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I am using jQuery Drag and Drop list [Demo & Documentation](http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/)

Drag and Drop is working fine When Page loads.

```
<li class="unmapped" value="11111" draggable="true">Employee111</li>
```

Once user saves the list, Reloading the list through Ajax call. After that Drag and drop is not working.

I found draggable attribute missing in li **"draggable="true"**

```
<li class="unmapped" value="11111">Employee111</li>
```

I called Draggablelist() in Ajax Success method. But that is also not working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use connectWith in Your Ajax Success method:

```
success: function (data) {
  $('#sortable1, #sortable2').sortable({
     connectWith: '.connected'
  });
}
```